# On calling web service in AsyncTask, Application crashed with exception "has leaked window"

Tags: android, web-services, exception, android-asynctask, memory-leaks

Follow is the code which produce exception only when I try to call method soapPHP() otherwise it run perfectly. I exhausted now after did many attempts to solve this problem. Any help will be appreciable from you guys.

```
private ProgressDialog pd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ThemeUtils.sTheme = ThemeUtils.THEME_BLUE;

    ThemeUtils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(MainMenuActivity.this);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu_screen);

    asynThread = new AsynThread();

    handler = new Handler() 
    {
        @Override
        public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            super.dispatchMessage(msg);
            dispLayMsg(globalMessage);
        }
    };

    asynThread.execute(GET_MAIN_MENU);

}
```

--

```
public Object soapPHP(String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION, String NAMESPACE, String URL)  
{
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
    request.addProperty("yourName", "Mohsin"); 

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
    new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
    httpTransport.debug = true;
    Object response = null;
    try {

        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        response = envelope.getResponse();

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
    }

    return response;
}
```

--

```
public class AsynThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
    private String inputParam = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainMenuActivity.this, "Attention..",
            "Please wait");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        inputParam = params[0];
        if (inputParam.equalsIgnoreCase(GET_MAIN_MENU)) 
        {
            menu_adapter = new MenuListAdapter();
            MenuListItem item = new MenuListItem();

            item.setMenu_name("Menu");

            item.setMenu_desc("Menu Description");

            menu_adapter.add(item);

            Object obj = soapPHP(METHOD_NAME, SOAP_ACTION, NAMESPACE, URL);

            menu_adapter.add(item);

            menu_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_menu_list);

            menu_list.setAdapter(menu_adapter);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();
        /*
        * if (inputParam.equalsIgnoreCase(UPLOAD)) { // uploadData(); }
        */
    }

}
```

--

EXCEPTION in LogCat:

```
07-30 17:51:10.882: E/WindowManager(5916): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.tgu.sample.onlinemenu.ui.MainMenuActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4052db78 that was originally added here
```

Comment: This error comes in many situations in your case I think you are trying to do some think that must be done in UI thread. Try creating menu list item in post execute or in on progress update

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's happens because your trying to run ProgressDialog on UiThread and it's has to run on a different thread.

You can try it to use like this

```
public class AsyncTaskHttpGet extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
private IHttpCallbackHandler _dataListener;
private ProgressDialog _dialog;
private Context mContext;

public AsyncTaskHttpGet(IHttpCallbackHandler dataListener, ProgressDialog dialog, Context context) {
    _dataListener = dataListener;
    _dialog = dialog;
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    //todo: request via GET to certain URL
    return HttpClientWrapper.HttpGet(urls[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if ( _dialog != null ) {
        if (_dialog.isShowing()) {
            _dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
    _dataListener.OnHttpRequestDoneLoad(result); //gets data oncomplete
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    if ( _dialog != null ) {
        _dialog.setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.load_data));
        _dialog.show();
    }
}

public interface IHttpCallbackHandler {
    void OnHttpRequestDoneLoad(String result);
}
```

}